# is it possible to define @Column at both field and getter method

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistence

> @MappedSuperclass 
> public abstract class BaseEntity implements
>   org.springframework.security.acls.model.ObjectIdentity {
>
> ```
> private static final long serialVersionUID = 7620579745392806460L;
>
> @Transient
> private String type;
>
> private Long id;
>
> @Column(name = "owner_user_id")
> private Long ownerUserId;
>
> @Column(name="id" , unique=true, updatable=false, nullable=false)
> @Id
> @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
> public Long getId() {
>     return this.id;
> }
> ```
>
> }

My Question is it allowed that for few field i can define @Column at the property and for few on the access-or.

**Second Question** : Is there is any way i can define separate hibernate sequence for set of classes. But the hurdle is the id field is defined in BaseEntity Class.

**Third Question** : please provide me good tutorial where i can found more on performance improvement

**Fourth Question** : we have multiple portal running on same BD with single hibernate sequence . Is it possible to define hibernate sequence at Entity Factory Level ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**First Answer**: Yes, it is. If you define on the property it takes the value from the property. If you define on the method, it takes the value returned by the method.

**Second Answer**: Yes, if you are using inheritance...

**Third Answer**: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html

**Fourth Answer**: How about creating your on sequence?
http://blog.anorakgirl.co.uk/2009/01/custom-hibernate-sequence-generator-for-id-field/

Cheers,